# Set Crystal Reports ParameterField to NULL at runtime

Tags: crystal-reports, vb6, crystal-reports-8.5

I have a Crystal Reports 8.5 report that uses a Stored Procedure as a data source. This Stored Procedure has a couple of parameters of which some are optional and require to be `Null` when executing the procedure.

In VB6 I tried to clear the parameter but then Crystal Reports prompts the user to enter a value. Then I tried setting it to `Nothing` but that gives an Invalid Type error. See the code below for an example of the `ParameterField` part.

```
Dim crApp As CRAXDRT.Application
Dim crRep As CRAXDRT.Report

Set crApp = New CRAXDRT.Application
Set crRep = crApp.OpenReport(ReportFile, 1)

'Option 1
crRep.ParameterFields(1).ClearCurrentValueAndRange '<-- This won't set it to Null but it clears the current value. User gets a prompt to enter a value.

'Option 2
crRep.ParameterFields(1).ClearCurrentValueAndRange
crRep.ParameterFields(1).AddCurrentValue Nothing '<-- Setting it to nothing gives an error at runtime
```

So how to set a parameter to `Null` at runtime?

Answer (score 4):

You have to set the parameterfield to `Empty`.

```
crRep.ParameterFields(1).ClearCurrentValueAndRange
crRep.ParameterFields(1).AddCurrentValue Empty
```

This will set it to `Null` when executing the Stored Procedure. Sometimes you even have to set it to `Empty` while the current value already is `Empty`. Because when you `Print` the report it still could prompt the user for input.